# regex: find "bar" but not "foo bar"

Tags: java, regex

We want to search a file to find all instances of "bar" that are not preceded by "foo" (ignoring preceding whitespaces and anything after.)

so if we have

```
foo
foo bar
baz
    bar a bunch of monkeys
```

we would only return lines 1 and 4

Comment: @Pshemo -- my bad, I will correct the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The pattern would look like this:

```
(?<!foo )bar
```

It's up to you to decide what "search a file" means. Read it line-by-line?

Comment: the reading the file bit isn't the issue. I had never come across the negative look-behind before

Comment: In the end we used (?m)^(?<!foo).\s*bar to capture some un-mentioned corner cases.